# Nginx "Server not found" while no network connection

Tags: nginx, yii2

I'm using LEMP stack on Ubuntu 14.04 and have some trouble with nginx/1.10.0., when I have no network connection I can't reach my local sites just see "Server not found", but there is some thing interesting the localhost site still works fine in any network state. I have 5 local sites but only stock localhost works perfect in any network state.
I try many settings combination of my nginx, hosts file, also rename site directory, given any permissions to www folder but nothing helps, I don't know what to do else. Also I notice if I visit site while I'm online i can use site a while after I go offline, but if I open browser console and set mode "no cache" in same second I loosing connection with site and see again "Server not found", and last, in any mode of networking off/lan/wlan local site address pings good, there is no trouble.
There is no error message in logs, all perfect clear.
My config files almost the same for all sites, here it is.

**My localhost nginx file**

```
    server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name localhost www.localhost;
    root        /home/arthur/www/localhost;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # uncomment to avoid processing of calls to non-existing static files by Yii
    #location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
    #    try_files $uri =404;
    #}
    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**my iamma.s nginx file**

```
    server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name iamma.s www.iamma.s;
    root        /home/arthur/www/iamma.s/web;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # uncomment to avoid processing of calls to non-existing static files by Yii
    #location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
    #    try_files $uri =404;
    #}
    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

**hosts file**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Arthur-ProBook
127.0.0.1   phpmyadmin
127.0.0.1   my.s
127.0.0.1   iamma.s
127.0.0.1   www.iamma.s
127.0.0.1   inv.s
127.0.0.1   www.phpmyadmin
127.0.0.1   www.my.s
127.0.0.1   www.inv.s

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: What `ping iamma.s` shows?

Comment: all ok in any state

Comment: Check your browser settings. Especially DNS and proxy

Comment: No, nothing has changed. Try to run safe mode browser, also nothing. More ideas you have?

Comment: Does simple `curl -v iamma.s` works?

Comment: Yes, it see all sites without connection.

Comment: Well, then it definitely browser issue.

Comment: Yes, I off all search suggestions in Chromium and it start work, but in Mozilla still not works

Comment: Ok, so no more questions here, many thanks for help, I will try to reinstall Firefox, and if it not helps I will write to Mozilla community forum.